# Microsoft Family Safety app blocking not reliable

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I have a Windows 10 tablet for my kid. I have it setup through Microsoft Family Safety such that certain app is blocked. I tested it and it worked. However, I found out that my kid can simply bypass the protection by uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: " found out that my kid can simply bypass the protection by uninstalling and reinstalling the app." - The simplest solution would be to revoke the account's ability to install applications.  I suggest using [Windows AppLocker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-8-applocker-step-by-step-guide) to block the executation of the exectuable.

Comment: If you provide more details, I am willing to do research, and submit a full answer.

Comment: Also, it is very easy to hack Family Safety if the `.exe` is writable. You can just replace the `.exe` with another one and FS doesn't care.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here. It seems it has something to do with the fact that the app is already "owned". And therefore one can uninstall and reinstall and the Family Safety cannot block it. There is also no way to "un-own" an app.

The only way that I am aware is to Block Windows Store (also an App) altogether. That way, Uninstalled Apps cannot be reinstalled.